# grep: -c: unknown option

Tags: linux, cron, alias, ksh, built-in

I'm trying to troubleshoot an intermittent error with a cron script that is deployed throughout a lot of systems that I inherited.

Here's the gist of the script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
command_output=`echo hi | grep -c ay`
```

Here is the intermittent error from the cron output:

```
grep: -c: unknown option
Usage: grep [-a name] opstring name [args...]
```

I haven't figured out how to duplicate the identical error when running the script interactively.

Instead, when I try to force this error using dummy code in the script (eg, grep -J ay), this is what I see:

```
grep: invalid option -- 'J'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
```

Because the error messages are different (ie, unknown vs invalid, Usage differences), I'm inferring that my cron job is using a different "grep" than when it is run interactively.

Can you please help me figure out how to duplicate the cron issue? Even better, can you share any hunches on how to fix this?

I suppose we can update the script on all of the systems to something like this:

```
command_output=$(echo hi | grep ay | wc -l)
```

...but am not sure if there are better ideas.

Comment: Check the version of `grep`.

Comment: The version is GNU grep 2.20. Just curious, though: Considering the version is the same in both scenarios, how does the version matter?

Comment: Can you run `which grep` from the cronjob and also `which grep` from the shell?

Comment: /bin/grep for both

Comment: Suggest to hard-code (temporarily) the fully-qualified-path to grep in the scripts. Some systems can have different grep versions in different paths (one version supplied by the vendor, another version the gnu one). Things might be different than your assumptions.